# How to bind drop event for two connected lists

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, backbone.js

I am trying to make a web-app staring from this [backbonetutorials](https://github.com/antonioJs/backbonetutorials/tree/gh-pages/examples/todo-app).

I crated two connected lists which look like this one: [connect-lists from jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#connect-lists)

I need to update the `item view` ($("ul#right > li")) when the item change list.

- By using `jQueryUI` when I render the AppView I make:

  ```
  render: function render ()
  {

      $("ul").sortable({
          connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
      }).disableSelection();
  }
  ```
- I can trigger the event in AppView in this way and it works

  events: {
          "sortreceive": "onSortreceive",
          "sortremove": "onSortremove"
   } // it works but I have access to the full list
- Now I would like to trigger the event at ItemView level (I mean trigger the moved item)

  events: {
           "drop"                      : "onDrop"
     } // it does not trigger

P.S.:
I know how to accomplish this task by using jQuery but I would like to make it at `item view level`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this solution extremely helpful, so maybe it will be useful for other people as well.

In the AppView:

```
$( ".selector" ).sortable({
     receive: function(event, ui) { 
           ui.trigger("drop"); // this will trigger just the itemView
     }
});
```